# Mapping/organizing nested objects in node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I am trying to map nested objects myself without using something like [JoinJS](https://github.com/archfirst/joinjs), which works great to an extent until I want to correctly make my JSON look pretty.

Based on the SQL query, my output is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "city_name": "city 1 - some city name",
    "city_category": "city 1 - some category",
    "city_description": "city 1 - some city description",
    "city_id": 1,
    "store_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "city_name": "city 1 - some city name",
    "city_category": "city 1 - some category",
    "city_description": "city 1 - some city description",
    "city_id": 1,
    "store_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "city_name": "city 1 - some city name",
    "city_category": "city 1 - some category",
    "city_description": "city 1 - some city description",
    "city_id": 1,
    "store_id": 3
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "city_name": "city 2 - some city name",
    "city_category": "city 2 - some category",
    "city_description": "city 2 - some city description",
    "city_id": 2,
    "store_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "city_name": "city 2 - some city name",
    "city_category": "city 2 - some category",
    "city_description": "city 2 - some city description",
    "city_id": 2,
    "store_id": 2
  }
]
```

I am trying to make this output look like this:

```
[
  {
    "city_id": 1,
    "city_name": "city 1 - some city name",
    "city_category": "city 1 - some category",
    "city_description": "city 1 - some city description",
    "store_ids": [1,2,3]
  }
  {
    "city_id": 2,
    "city_name": "city 2 - some city name",
    "city_category": "city 2 - some category",
    "city_description": "city 2 - some city description",
    "store_ids": [1,2]
  }
]
```

My first guess is that I need to find all the unique `id`'s or `city_id`'s using `_.chain(result).uniqBy('city_id').value()`. But then I am a bit stuck on removing the `id` from the output and most of all, how to create a new key `store_ids` that has an array of all the stores per city. Make sense?

Using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) or just plain JS (no other modules like JoinJS, unless they are efficient for things like this), how would I manipulate this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run through the results, and group them in to my new object results.
In the end you will have an object of object that the key is the item.id,
but if you would like to convert it to array it's simple.

```
let resultsObject = {};

sqlQueryRows.map(function(item) {
   if (item.id in resultsObject) {
       resultsObject[item.id].store_ids.push(item.store_id);
   } else {
       resultsObject[item.id] = {
           city_id: item.city_id,
           city_name: item.city_name,
           city_category: item.city_category,
           city_description: item.city_description,
           store_ids: [item.store_id] 
       }
   }
});

// if you need an array
let resultsArray = Object.values(resultsObject);
```

Comment: From a readability and visual organization standpoint, this answer made the most sense to me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my lodash approach:

```
_(data)
  .uniqBy('city_id')
  .map(_.partialRight(_.omit, 'store_id'))
  .map(i => _.defaults({
    store_ids: _(data)
      .filter({ city_id: i.city_id })
      .map('store_id')
      .value()
  }, i))
  .value();
```

The idea is to:

- Get the unique cities.
- Remove the storage IDs.
- Create the storage IDs array by filtering the original data by the unique city IDs.

Comment: Appreciate the answer!! I ended up using the other approach (I didn't realize how complex lodash can get), but thank you so much for your help!! I had no clue even how to begin getting lodash to work before your input.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just trying to remove certain fields you can use the .map method, but I'm not sure I understand the question entirely.

```
var new_array = array_name.map((val) => {
    //do stuff to array
}
```

Comment: Hey jsq324 thanks for getting back to me! I edited my question a bit.

_My first guess is that I need to find all the unique `id`'s or `city_id`'s using `_.chain(result).uniqBy('city_id').value()`. But then I am a bit stuck on removing the `id` from the output and most of all, how to create a new key `store_ids` that has an array of all the stores per city._